# Solr 6 on Windows fails when creating new collection

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am using Solr 6.1.0 on a Windows 7 machine.

- I have downloaded Solr 6 from here : http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/6.1.0
- I have downloaded the server JRE (8u92) from here : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html
- I have written this BAT file to start Solr:

  ```
  set JAVA_HOME="F:\Users\username\Downloads\solr-6.1.0\jdk1.8.0_92\"
  cd "F:\Users\username\Downloads\solr-6.1.0\bin\"
  solr start -e cloud -noprompt
  ```

The problem : The Solr management UI runs just fine and I can query the sample collection, but when I try to create a new connection I get errors:

```
Collection: collection1 operation: create failed:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not end with / character
at org.apache.zookeeper.common.PathUtils.validatePath(PathUtils.java:58)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1024)
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$5.execute(SolrZkClient.java:314)
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$5.execute(SolrZkClient.java:311)
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkCmdExecutor.retryOperation(ZkCmdExecutor.java:60)
at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.exists(SolrZkClient.java:311)
at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.validateConfig(OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.java:2491)
at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.createCollection(OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.java:1838)
at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.processMessage(OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.java:224)
at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerTaskProcessor$Runner.run(OverseerTaskProcessor.java:463)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$22(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Path must not end with / character
at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:273)
at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:204)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:156)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:663)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:445)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:257)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:208)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

By searching on the web I found old posts that didn't seem to help much and I am really a newbie to servlets and the way they work.
I don't have Tomcat (All I did is described above. The only thing missing from above is the extraction of the archives in the desired folder), so I guess I use the built-in Jetty server.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: How are you adding your new collection? Through the admin interface, or via an HTTP request?

Comment: @MattPearce Through the admin interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When adding a new collection to a multiple core (ie. cloud-based) Solr instance, you need to specify a configset alongside your collection name. There is a drop-down under the **name** text box on the form. For the example SolrCloud configuration, the only option available is `gettingstarted`.

If you don't supply the configset, you get the "Path must not end with / character" error you describe.

Incidentally, you don't need to worry about Tomcat. Prior to Solr 5, it was possible to deploy Solr within a web server such as Tomcat or JBoss. This was discouraged from Solr 5, and is no longer supported - Solr runs as a standalone service, using a built-in Jetty instance to serve content.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have just managed to create the new collection. :)